# How to pass useState setter as param? What is the type for it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this use state:

```js
const [imgIdUploded, setImageIdUploaded] = useState<string | undefined>(
    undefined
)
```

What type to write?

```
export default function BuyTicketForm(props: {
    setImageIdUploaded?: ?????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gonna be the type of `Dispatch<SetStateAction<YOUR_TYPE>`

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

export default function BuyTicketForm(props: {
    setImageIdUploaded?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | undefined>>
```

Comment: @János updated OP